# React hook form controller render return [Function Anonymous] instead of array of data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hook-form

I need the value from skillsInput to be an array but whenever I try to check the data from Detail it shows that skills return [Function Anonymous] not the actual data even though when I log the items (value: items) from SkillsInput it shows the array of data that has been inputed

the defaultValue is worked, it shows [] when skills are empty then it shows [Function Anonymous] when I add a new value on SkillsInput

the error on Detail is shown as

> skills must be a `array` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value [Function anonymous]).
> If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`

Detail.js

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  skills: yup
    .array()
    .min(1, "at least one skill needed")
    .typeError("dev: typeError")
    .required("required"),
  preference: yup
    .array()
    .min(1, "at least one preference needed")
    .typeError("dev: typeError")
    .required("required"),
})
export default function Detail() {
const { control, handleSubmit, setValue, getValues } = useForm({
    mode: "onBlur",
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
  });
return(
  <View>
    <SkillsInput name="skills" control={control} />
    <PreferencesInput name="preference" control={control} />
  </View>
)}
```

SkillsInput.js

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required("Required"),
  duration: yup.string().required("Required"),
});

export default ({
  name = "skills",
  control: parentControl,
  defaultValue = [],
}) => {
  const [selectedIndex, setIndex] = React.useState("");
  const { control, handleSubmit, reset, setValue, getValues, setError } =
    useForm({
      mode: "onBlur",
      resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    });
  const renderForm = ({
    field: { onChange: setItems, value: items },
    fieldState: { error },
  }) => {
    const onSubmit = () => {
      const name = getValues("name");
      const duration = getValues("duration");
      const newItem = { name, duration };
      if (!selectedIndex) {
        const isExist = items.some((item) => item.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase());
        if (isExist) {
          setError("name", {
            type: "manual",
            message: "Skill has been inputed",
          });
          return;
        }
        setItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, newItem]);
      } else {
        const isExist = items.some(
          (item, idx) => item.name.toLowerCase() === name.toLowerCase() && idx !== +selectedIndex
        );
        if (isExist) {
          setError("name", {
            type: "manual",
            message: "Skill has been inputed",
          });
          return;
        }
        setItems((prevItems) =>
          prevItems.map((item, idx) =>
            idx === +selectedIndex ? newItem : item
          )
        );
      }
      clearInput();
    };
    const clearInput = () => {
      setIndex("");
      reset({
        name: "",
        duration: "",
      });
    };
    const ListItemIcon = (props, item, index) => {
      return (
        <>
          <IconButton
            {...props}
            icon="pencil"
            onPress={() => {
              setValue("name", item.name);
              setValue("duration", item.duration);
              setIndex(String(index));
            }}
          />
          <IconButton
            {...props}
            icon="delete"
            onPress={() => {
              const filteredItems = items?.filter(
                (_, currentIndex) => currentIndex !== index
              );
              setItems(filteredItems);
              clearInput();
            }}
          />
        </>
      );
    };
    return (
      <ModalInput
        label="Skills"
        textVal={
          items?.length >= 1 ? `${items.length} skill` : undefined
        }
        error={error}
      >
        <AppTextInput
          name="name"
          label="Skill"
          placeholder="Skill"
          autoCorrect={true}
          control={control}
        />
        <AppPicker
          name="duration"
          label="Time"
          placeholder="Time"
          items={[
            { value: "< 1 year" },
            { value: "1 - 3 year" },
            { value: "> 3 year" },
          ]}
          control={control}
        />
        <Button
          labelStyle={styles.btnSubmit}
          mode="contained"
          onPress={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
          color={Colors.blue500}
        >
          Edit
        </Button>
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(_, i) => String(i)}
          data={items}
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentFlatList}
          renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
            return (
              <List.Item
                style={styles.listItem}
                title={item.name}
                description={item.duration}
                right={(props) => ListItemIcon(props, item, index)}
              />
            );
          }}
        />
      </ModalInput>
    );
  };
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={parentControl}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      render={renderForm}
    />
  );
};
```

Here is the data that I get when I log SkillsInput items

```json
Array [
  Object {
    "duration": "> 3 year",
    "name": "test",
  },
  Object {
    "duration": "1 - 3 year",
    "name": "test2",
  },
]
```

> NB: PreferencesInput would have similar data as SkillsInput

Comment: Your `schema` definition in `Detail.js` doesn't look right to me based on this [documentation](https://github.com/jquense/yup#array). I guess it should be `yup.array().of(skill);` where skill is similar to [object](https://github.com/jquense/yup#object), which describes only fields of a single skill.

Comment: I think I made a little mistake in my question.. in the future, `Detail.js` schema would contain several arrays just like skills that's why I write it like that

I'll add this info to my question

Comment: My point is that `skills: yup.array()` doesn't describe the object structure you expect. It doesn't answer the question "array of what?".

Comment: what i believe is that using `yup.array.of()` is optional since it will validate it's contents and I don't think I need it since I already validate it on `SkillsInput.js`, but then i tried using `skills: yup.array().of(yup.object({name: yup.string().required("Required"), duration: yup.string().required("Required"),}))` and it still has the same error